# Character encoding in JSON en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, character-encoding

I have a problem regarding encoding.

I created a MySQL 5.5 DB containing some text. I also create a Java Webservice which creates JSON which is read by an Android application.

I have stored text in the DB and it looks good, for example :

***verwarm de oven voor op 210°C***

But when I check the JSON in the browser it looks like this (and also in my Android app)

***{"gerechtId":"6","id":"13","laatsteUpdate":"2013-02-14T15:53:42+01:00","text":"verwarm de oven voor op 210Â°C","titel":"oven voorverwarmen","volgNr":"1"}***

As you can see, the temperature is showing characters I don't like ;-)

How can I avoid this ?

I'm using Hibernate 3 for reading the db. Here is my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
    <persistence-unit name="LENGO" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://62.213.197.17/lengotoo_autikoken?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: when you render it as JSON, are you setting http response type UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by doing this :

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF-8")
```

instead of

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

in the resources of my webservice.